# Wordpress Settings API callbacks

Tags: wordpress

Does Wordpress settings API have any way of passing custom arguments to the callbacks or something? So I don't have to define seventeen hundred callbacks?

Or knowing the field/section/group name so I can do for example a text input handler that does:

```
$options = get_option( $setting );
echo "<input id='$option_id' name='$setting[$field]' size='40' 
       type='text' value='{$options[$field]}' />";
```

instead of a different callback for each field with all those values hardcoded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an optional parameter $args which carries an array of parameters. What I did was to set it to this:

```
array('option' => $this->optionsPrefix.'server'));
```

and then do this in the common calback

```
function display_text_option($args)
{
    $args = array_merge(array(
        'option' => '',
        'pass' => false), $args);

    $option = $args['option'];

    $options = get_option(LDFOPTION);

    if($options == null)
        $options = array();

    $options = array_merge(array(
        $option => ''), $options);

    $value = $options[$option];
    $type = $args['pass']?'password':'text';
    echo " <input id='$option', name='".LDFOPTION."[$option]' size='40' type='$type' value='$value' />";
}
```

I'll probably do some more refactoring later on as thoughts come up